# RabbitMQ won't start after power failure

Tags: crash, erlang, centos, rabbitmq

I'm running a RabbitMQ server instance on my machine. But after a power failure in the building I can't get Rabbit to start.

There is no other service running on the same TCP-port and I've tried to reinstall both rabbit and erlang but nothing seems to work.

I'm running:

- CentOS release 5.4 (Final)
- Rabbit rabbitmq-server-2.8.2-1.noarch
- erlang-R14B-03.3.el5.x86_64

The startup_error log is empty but the startup_log contains:

```
{
error_logger,
{
    {2012,5,10},
    {9,35,43}
},
"Protocol: ~p: register error: ~p~n",
[
    "inet_tcp",
    {
        {
            badmatch,
            {
                error,
                econnrefused
            }
        },
        [
            {
                inet_tcp_dist,
                listen,
                1
            },
            {
                net_kernel,
                start_protos,
                4
            },
            {
                net_kernel,
                start_protos,
                3
            },
            {
                net_kernel,
                init_node,
                2
            },
            {
                net_kernel,
                init,
                1
            },
            {
                gen_server,
                init_it,
                6
            },
            {
                proc_lib,
                init_p_do_apply,
                3
            }
        ]
    }
]
}{
error_logger,
{
    {2012,5,10},
    {9,35,43}
},
crash_report,
[
    [
        {
            initial_call,
            {
                net_kernel,
                init,
                [
                    'Argument__1'
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            pid,
            <0.20.0>
        },
        {
            registered_name,
            [

            ]
        },
        {
            error_info,
            {
                exit,
                {
                    error,
                    badarg
                },
                [
                    {
                        gen_server,
                        init_it,
                        6
                    },
                    {
                        proc_lib,
                        init_p_do_apply,
                        3
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            ancestors,
            [
                net_sup,
                kernel_sup,
                <0.9.0>
            ]
        },
        {
            messages,
            [

            ]
        },
        {
            links,
            [
                #Port<0.90>,
                <0.17.0>
            ]
        },
        {
            dictionary,
            [
                {
                    longnames,
                    false
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            trap_exit,
            true
        },
        {
            status,
            running
        },
        {
            heap_size,
            610
        },
        {
            stack_size,
            24
        },
        {
            reductions,
            509
        }
    ],
    [

    ]
]
}{
error_logger,
{
    {2012,5,10},
    {9,35,43}
},
supervisor_report,
[
    {
        supervisor,
        {
            local,
            net_sup
        }
    },
    {
        errorContext,
        start_error
    },
    {
        reason,
        {
            'EXIT',
            nodistribution
        }
    },
    {
        offender,
        [
            {
                pid,
                undefined
            },
            {
                name,
                net_kernel
            },
            {
                mfargs,
                {
                    net_kernel,
                    start_link,
                    [
                        [
                            rabbitmqprelaunch4868,
                            shortnames
                        ]
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                restart_type,
                permanent
            },
            {
                shutdown,
                2000
            },
            {
                child_type,
                worker
            }
        ]
    }
]
}{
error_logger,
{
    {
        2012,
        5,
        10
    },
    {
        9,
        35,
        43
    }
},
supervisor_report,
[
    {
        supervisor,
        {
            local,
            kernel_sup
        }
    },
    {
        errorContext,
        start_error
    },
    {
        reason,
        shutdown
    },
    {
        offender,
        [
            {
                pid,
                undefined
            },
            {
                name,
                net_sup
            },
            {
                mfargs,
                {
                    erl_distribution,
                    start_link,
                    [

                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                restart_type,
                permanent
            },
            {
                shutdown,
                infinity
            },
            {
                child_type,
                supervisor
            }
        ]
    }
]
}{
error_logger,
{
    {
        2012,
        5,
        10
    },
    {
        9,
        35,
        43
    }
},
std_info,
[
    {
        application,
        kernel
    },
    {
        exited,
        {
            shutdown,
            {
                kernel,
                start,
                [
                    normal,
                    [

                    ]
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        type,
        permanent
    }
]
}{
"Kernel pid terminated",
application_controller,
"{application_start_failure,kernel,{shutdown,{kernel,start,[normal,[]]}}}"
}
```

Anyone got an idea?

Comment: have you checked to see if a part of it is running already.  try a ps and see if something is started that is blocking it starting fully.

Comment: check if epmd is running, if so, kill it

Comment: I completely forgot about this question. Yes, the problem was that something used the same port. I got the error one more time after it was resolved and if I am not mistaken, it was the epmd that was still running. As @bighostkim commented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

econnrefused in the beginning clearly indicates that something's listening on the same port, **netstat -plten** could have shown what was it.

Comment: I completely forgot about this question. Yes, the problem was that something used the same port. I got the error one more time after it was resolved and if I am not mistaken, it was the epmd that was still running. As @bighostkim commented.